# How to insert a line at the beginning of a file with sed?

Tags: sed

Im trying to insert a line containing these characters: `~o` to the beginning of a file. Im using: `sed -i '' "1s/^/~o \n/" macros` But the newline option just doesn't do its job. How should I change it ? Thank you

Comment: I tested your command after giving my answer. It works for me. What problem did you had with that.

Comment: When I run my command, I receive no error, but the characters are appended at the beginning of the first line of the file, not in a separate line. So Im wondering why \n doesn't work?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the insert command `i`:

```
sed '1i\TEXT TO INSERT' file
```

Explanation:

```
1     Addresses the first line
i     The insert command inserts the following
      text before(!) line 1
\     Required after i (in POSIX compatible versions of sed)
TEXT  The text to insert
```

Example:

```
sed '1i\Hello' <<< 'world!'
```

Output:

```
Hello
world!
```

---

Btw, `i` works even with newline characters:

```
sed '1i\Hello\n' <<< 'world'
```

Output:

```
Hello

world!
```

Comment: Sorry for delay,  hek2mgl. I tried your suggestion: sed '1i\~o\n' macros But I receive this error: sed: 1: "1i\~o\n": extra characters after \ at the end of i command

Comment: Which version of sed are you using? Which OS?

Comment: Im not sure if this is what you are looking for, nbut when I write what /usr/bin/sed, its what I receive: PROGRAM:sed  PROJECT:text_cmds-87